# Проблема с коллекцией java

Tags: java, коллекции, hashmap

HashMap  в корзине,номер которой получается на основе хешкода,с помощью метода equals сравнивает ключ который мы добавляем со всеми ключами которые хранятся в данной ячейке,и если equals не вернул true ни для какого ключа ,тоесть ключи не равны ,добавляется новое ключ=значение,я преопределил 
метод equals для определенного обьекта так что он всегда возвращает false,и добавляю один и тот же ключ (этот обьект) 1000 раз,но добавляется только 1,как хешсет понимает что это один и тот же ключ и не добавляет его снова и снова если сравнивая этот ключ по equals всегда получаем false?Знаю ,вероятно эт[image: введите сюда описание изображения]о тупой вопрос и ответ очевидный,но я учусь,буду благодарен за любою помощь,спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данной реализации протокол ненарушен посколько при true equals(что не возможно по задумке) одинаковй хешкод

Comment: Отлично про эту ситуацию расписано здесь: https://habr.com/ru/post/168195/ . Вы нарушили контракт hashCode и equals.

Comment: Ну формально контракт не нарушен. Я бы поставил на то, что для оптимизации перед equals на == проверка есть в реализации.

Comment: Если я преопределя метод hashcode() так что он всегда возвращает одно и тоже число ,например 1,то получается что нарушение протокола нет так как ,при true equals,хешкод равен,при работе с мапой мы получаем логорифмический рост поиска тк все обьекты данного класса взвращают один хешкод и следовательно записываются в одну и ту же корзину,но при проверке на наличие ключа который мы добавляем в данной мапе,equals всегда возвращет false,следовательно для программы этого ключа нет в данной корзине и он должен быть добавлен,но это не так,дабавляется только 1 элемент

Comment: В этом коде нет никакого практического примениния,я лишь играюсь с целью понять логику работы колекций,и как я знаю,в HashMap могутт быть одинаковые значение но не одинаковые ключи,и для того что бы понять что ключ одинаковый используется метод equals,true значение которого говорит о дубликате,но если он всегда возвращает false,следовательно ключ не может быть дубликатом поумолчанию,и должен добавляться какое угодно количество раз

Comment: @pavel Нет, формально контракт нарушен. По стандарту hashCode определяется от области в памяти, а equals - сравнивает ссылки. Он переопределил только equals, создав возможной ситуацию, когда hashCode-ы не равны, а сами объекты по equals равны

Comment: @Miron как?? если equals всегда false возвращает. Кстати hashCode отвязали от области памяти по большому счёту.

Comment: @Miron `equals = false` всегда! Мапа не сможет найти существующий ключ! Да, она может найти тот же бакет, но то же сочетание `key=value` никогда!

Comment: @Imagination Так получается ибо Вы используете один и тот же объект для всех значений которые вы кладете в мапу. При добавлении создавайте каждый раз новый объект.

Comment: @Tsyklop,единственно непонятная вещь для меня это откуда java знает что это один и тот же обьект если для определения она использует метод equals,который всегда возвращает false

Comment: Как я начал понимать false по equals недостаточно для того что бы признать обьекты не равными нужно ещё false по ==,это так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он вам все правильно выдает. Вы ему в качестве ключа, передаете всегда один и тот же объект, он ему просто 1000 раз меняет значение.Чтоб получилось 1000 объектов в мапе вы должны создание объекта поместить во внутрь цикла.

```
 for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++){
     set1.put( new TestMe(),i);
 }
```

Первое что там проверяется это hashCode. Метод put

```
 public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
 }
```

метод hash

```
 static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
 }
```

ну и метод putVal

```
 final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
               boolean evict) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
    if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
        n = (tab = resize()).length;
    if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
        tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
    else {
        Node<K,V> e; K k;
        if (p.hash == hash &&
            ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            e = p;
        else if (p instanceof TreeNode){

        ...
```

Comment: Я не понимаю как он определяет что это один и тот же обьект,ведь для определения он использует метод equals,а я его преопределил что он всегда возвращает false,следовательно программа не может понять что это 1 и тот же обьет и должна добавить его 1000 раз,в этом вопрос

Comment: Тоесть что бы понять что это один и тотже обьект происходит проверка element.equals(element)-и она возвращает false,следовательно по логике программы это разные обьекты

Comment: Там не настолько банальная логика :) , Первое что там сравнивается это hashCode, который у вас одинаковый. Добавлю в ответ

Comment: я добавил объяснение в ответ. Если интересно, поставьте точку останова в метод putVal и сможете сами все увидеть

Comment: @Z.John ну как бы сравнивает он `hash`, но ведь там стоит оператор `&&` и это значит что он будет вызывать и `equals`, который ВСЕГДА возвращает `false`. Следовательно должно быть 1000 значений.

Comment: @Tsyklop `(k = p.key) == key` сравнение на ==. О чём я собственно и писал в комментарии)

Comment: @pavel `==` сравнивает ссылки. `set1.put(new TestMe(), i);` - тут Всегда ссылки будут разные на объекты. не пойму к чему Ваш комментарий тут.

Comment: @pavel там еще как бы есть `|| (key != null && key.equals(k)))` часть, которая сравнивает через метод `equals`.

Comment: @pavel ааа. у автора беда в коде) там юзается один и тот же объект

Comment: о чем я написал в самом начале ответа

Comment: @Z.John да, просто не на то место в коде акцент сделали. Я бы посоветовал именно это место выделить.

Comment: @pavel я сначала только его и написал, если почитаете первые два комментария под ответом -то поймете.Пришлось лезть глубже :)

Comment: Если я правильно понял то помимо equals,ещё идет сравнение по ссылкам и даже если equals возвращает false а по == обьекты равны,то Map понимает что это 1 и тот же обьект?

Comment: И то что это один и тот же обьект это не ошибка,это тест,я умышленно это делаю,пытаясь понять как Map определяет что это один и тот же обьект а не 2 разных,как я знаю для этого используется метод equals,и если он определен как false всегда то логично что она добавит один и тот же обьект сколько угодно раз,я так понял по вашим ответам что для добавления мало false по equals, нужно ещё != по ссылкам,если так то тему можно считать закрытой

Comment: @Imagination закрывать задачи на сайте принято принятием ответа, галочкой слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Вы нарушили контракт **hashCode()** и **equals()**.

Соглашение между equals и hashCode в Java

1. Если объекты равны по результатам выполнения метода equals, тогда их
   hashcode должны быть одинаковыми.
2. Если объекты не равны по результатам выполнения метода equals, тогда
   их hashcode могут быть как одинаковыми, так и разными. Однако
       для повышения производительности, лучше, чтобы разные объекты
       возвращали разные коды.

   Вы обязаны переопределять оба метода ***equals()*** и ***hashCode()*** в Java. Метод hashCode используется в hash -коллекциях(например HashMap), и чем меньше будет коллизий (одинаковый код при разных объектах) тем эффективнее эти коллекции будут работать с объектами вашего класса.

Comment: Я это знаю,но это просто тест в целях обучения.При этом обьекты никогда не равны по equals,ведь equals всегда возвращает false,следовательно нет необходимости следить за тем что бы при true equals были одинаковые хешкоды.Если переопределить метод hashcode() так что он возвращает всегда одно значение например 5,мы получаем неоптимальный алгоритм поиска поскольку всу обькеты хранятся в одной корзине тк у них одинаковый хешкод,но при этом сам алгоритм ведь заключается в том что если у обьектов одинаковый хешкод тоесть одна корзина,то в этой корзине они сравниваются по equals,и если equals не true

Comment: происходит добавление в корзину новой ключ=значение пары,тк нет такого ключа,поскольку по equals не найден дубликат